# How to catch AskTimeoutException in Play using Java and Akka?

Tags: java, exception, playframework, akka, try-catch

I have public method in my service which returns me something depending on my query String. Everything goes well and it returns my desired CompletionStage with expected data. But I want to cover all possible events (eg IOFailure, or some runtime exception). I noticed that `ask()` method may thorw AskTimeoutException. I don't have an Idea how to catch this exception. I can't do this in regular try-catch block due to "AskTimeoutException is never thrown in corresponding block"

This is my method:

```
public CompletionStage<FindResponseMsg> find(String query, int limit) {
    FindMsg findMsg = new FindMsg(query, limit);
    // TODO timeout
    return FutureConverters.toJava(ask(indexerRouter, findFileMsg, 10000))
            .thenApply(response -> ((FindResponseMsg) response));

}
```

My question is how to catch failure at incoming Future?

Comment: Like you catch any other exception, surround it in a try catch?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this problem? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @Derrops No, this won't work as you described, and I ain't know how to do it. Maybe by creating a `scheduler` with timeout and catch in its body.